# Mongoose .lt dosen't work with post value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have this Mongoose function

```
exports.readSign = function(req, res) {
    if (req.user.roles.indexOf('admin') === 1) {

        Timesheet.find()
            .where('projectId').equals(req.params.projectId)
            .where('week').gt(req.params.startWeek - 1).lt(req.params.endWeek + 1)

            .sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName')
            .exec(function (err, timesheet) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    res.jsonp(timesheet);
                }
            });
    }
```

and route

```
app.route('/timesheets/sign/:projectId/:startWeek/:endWeek')
        .get(timesheets.readSign);
```

but my `.lt` doesn't work on post :/
http://localhost:3000/timesheets/sign/658/3/3

It returns an object with "week": 8

If I change `.lt(req.params.endWeek + 1)` to `.lt(3 + 1)` it doesn't return my object as it should, but it does with my post, in postman

`console log .lt(req.params.endWeek + 1)`  returns 3

why won't this use my post value ?? :)

Comment: Show your express route configuration.

Comment: @YuriZarubin added to question now

Answer (score 0):

You route is set to use.get(), not .post()

Change it to:

```
app.route('/timesheets/sign/:projectId/:startWeek/:endWeek')
        .post(timesheets.readSign);
```